# Why can't I put iPad app on my iPad for development?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

Previously, I've been able to push my apps to my iPad from Xcode 4.2.  I was building with Phonegap.  The process is: register my App ID with the dev center, create a provision profile, and download it into my Xcode.  Then from the drop down beside the play button in Xcode, I will see iPad as an option.

Now I'm building an iPhone app with Objective-C for the first time.  I repeated the process above, but I don't see my iPad listed beside the play button.  What is wrong?

Some ideas: i don't think my iPad has iOS 5.  i think it still might be running iOS 4.x.  Is that a possible reason?

Comment: You should be able to do this.  Apple provides the means for developers to download their own pending iOS applications.

Comment: This sounds like you've not set the Deployment Target for your application low enough. Click on your project in Xcode, go to the Build Settings tab, and look for the iOS Deployment Target. Make sure it's equal to or lower than the iOS version of your test iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible,

- Update everything to the latest version (Mac, Xcode, iPad, etc.)

---

## Provision a Device

- If you are a team administrator, or if your team administrator has already configured the necessary credentials for you and your device, you can use the devices organizer to automatically download and apply the provisioning profile.
- Alleviate the need to go to the iOS Provisioning Portal every time you want to add a device to your provisioning profile by using automatic provisioning.
- To provision a device automatically for development . . .

  1. Open the devices organizer.
  2. Plug in your device.
  3. Select the device, and click Use for Development.

[image: Xcode Organizer]

Developing apps requires a provisioned device. The provisioning process sets up the required certificates and configuration data that Xcode needs to install your apps on your device.

- [Xcode 4 User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Devices/Devices.html)

---

**It’s OK to support only the newest version of the OS.**

- [Matt Gemmell - Latest Version](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/12/05/latest-version/)